# netem packet loss for packets destined to the same machine

Tags: tcp, packet, delay

I am using a command like

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev eno1 root netem loss 10%
```

to delay all the outgoing packets over the interface `eno1`, but this won't work if the packets are destined for the same system. May be becuase (I think) the packets don't reach the interface, but is delivered much before that.

So, I want something that can delay the packets that are destined to the same system. **(source IP is same as destination IP)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to change the target device to the loopback interface.

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev lo root netem loss 10%
```